# What is the name of the sign indicating positive or negative numbers

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to describe patterns where there are numbers in pairs like these:
-1 and +1, -944 and +944.

Now I want to write a sentence that someone should "look for equal numbers just with opposite X". What is an appropriate word to fill in for X.

Comment: You literally say "equal magnitude, *opposite **[sign](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_(mathematics)***".

Comment: Why not try: **polarity**

Comment: Thank you @DanBron! Given your 5 upvotes for your comment, I would accept it as an answer if you write it as one.

Comment: @user3306356 Polarity sounds more intuitive.

Comment: Polarity is only for electricity.  It has quite a different meaning to the sign of a cartesian number.

Comment: I suppose, this being ELU, it's also worth pointing out the concept of [grammatical polarity](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item), which corresponds to "yes" and "no" (at a gross level). But it's also worth pointing out that binary distinction is the very reason we don't apply the word "polarity" to numbers (not even 'Cartesian' numbers ;) because it lacks the sense of neutrality (zero). Something which is polar is one extreme or the other. The sign of a number can be positive, negative, or neither. More details in the links in my question & its comments, for those interested.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pairs of numbers like ***1*** and **-1** or ***+944*** and **-944** are said to have

> Equal ***[magnitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value)***, but opposite ***[sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_(mathematics))***

Comment: Mathematician here — I second this answer, in my experience both among professional mathematicians and in talking to people who use maths in other fields.

Comment: I really can't even think of another word, in English!  I guess, if you're trying to sound formal in a text book, you could only say "is it positive or negative" (i.e., rather than "what's the sign, mate?")  I mean you could say direction if you were sort of dealing with vectors a lot, or similar.

Comment: @Joe, in a *mathematics* textbook, you would *definitely* call this the **sign**, because that is the official and correct mathematical term. Click through the link provided & read the article (or its own citations). In a formal setting, you couldn't say "positive or negative", because that characterization is incomplete: zero is neither positive nor negative (that is, the [signum function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signum_function) is *three*-valued). If you're looking for other, informal, terms, in my grammar school days, older teachers sometimes said "equal magnitude, opposite *senses*".

Comment: Yeah I suppose you could say "senses".  Really. It's wild that there's no "fancy" word for .. "sign!" Good one. (Regarding zero - I don't think anyone asked about it.  In "math" it's usually said to be different.  In say computing, you typically treat it as positive (the "sign function" if you will is different from the math one you mentioned , example, http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Sign.html  Two outputs.).  Perhaps the same in engineering, I don't really know. Anyway good one ..."sign" and nothing else!!!

Comment: @joe, Nah, that's just a sloppy implantation of `sgn`. Programming languages treat zero the same way math does, wrt sign. See, for example, the definition of the (three-valued) [signum function in the Java Standard Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#signum(double)) or any other major programming language.

Comment: Uh, yeah, sure  :)  In any event it's cool that "sign" is the only real term!  Awesome!

Comment: Not a Java man, huh? I know, lost its edge when it sold out to Oracle. I get you. Maybe you're a .NET guy then, like a little [C#, VB.NET, that kind of thing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywb0xks3(v=vs.110).aspx)? Or maybe you're a web developer, [JavaScript hacker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign)? Or one of these cool [functional programming hipsters](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:signum)? Or maybe you're not *positive* or *negative* on any of them, just kind of ... ***neutral***? ;)